# jQuery UI dialog in Bookmarklet and GreaseMonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, jquery-ui-dialog, bookmarklet

Thanks to some awesome answers in other threads, I learned how to:

- [load jQuery and jQuery-UI in a bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6551184/1596418)
- [load a CSS into a bookmarklet using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805406/1596418)
- [create a DIV in a bookmarklet using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8332887/1596418)
- [create jQuery UI dialog (external link)](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

and I could manage to combine all four things into a single script which works both as a BookMarklet and as a GreaseMonkey script, which is absolutely awesome.

However, it doesn't work on all sites. Neither the bookmarklet nor the GreaseMonkey script work on Wikipedia. 
I tried it on other sites and it works: amazon.com, msn.com, yahoo.com, news.google.com, stackoverflow.com and it works well.

Is it possible to make it work on wikipedia.org?

Also there is a minor issue: each second time I use the bookmarklet, the title of the dialog window doesnt show ('Basic dialog'). I wonder why, although it doesn't really matter - it's not important at all.

Here is the script:

```
javascript:(function () {
        function getScript(url, success) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;

            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var completed = false;
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!completed && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    completed = true;
                    success();
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    head.removeChild(script);
                }
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
        }

        getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js", function () {
            getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js", function () {
                var myStylesLocation = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";
                $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+myStylesLocation+'" >').appendTo("head");
                alert("It works");
                var myMessage = "This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information.";
                $("<div id='dialog'; title='Basic dialog'; style='border:2px solid black; background-color:lightblue; font-size:80%'; <p>" + myMessage + "</p></div>").appendTo("body");
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            });
        });
})();
```

Comment: [jQuery loaded that way conflicts with many websites](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).  See, also [Adding jQuery UI to Greasemonkey script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8688552/331508).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a script that works? At least in Bookmarklets.

Comment: now the script works, the problem was it needed "https" instead of "http"